# Rails API: Selecting records that match parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have the following `Pixel` model with the following attributes `media`, `page`, `disabled`, `selective`

And I am looking for the most reusable way to make an API call that selects all objects that match the parameters passed in the API call. The API call can take 0 parameters or any number of parameters

Here is what I have so far. I believe it will work, but I definitely think there has to be a better solution.

```
    def pixels_by_params
        if(params[:media] && params[:page] && params[:selective] && params[:disabled])
            pixels = TrackingPixel.media(params[:media]).page(params[:media]).selective(params[:selective]).disabled(params[:disabled])
        elsif(params[:media] && params[:page] && params[:selective])
            pixels = TrackingPixel.media(params[:media]).page(params[:media]).selective(params[:selective])
        elsif(params[:media] && params[:page])
            pixels = TrackingPixel.media(params[:media]).page(params[:media])
        elsif(params[:media])
            pixels = TrackingPixel.media(params[:media])
        ...
        ...
        ...
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're chaining all of them anyway, so why don't you just...

```
pixels = params[:media] ? TrackingPixel.media(params[:media]) : TrackingPixel.all
pixels = pixels.page(params[:page]) if params[:page]
pixels = pixels.selective(params[:selective]) if params[:selective]
pixels = pixels.disabled(params[:disabled]) if params[:disabled]
```

Or if you prefer a fancy-fied loop, you could:

```
pixels = params[:media] ? TrackingPixel.media(params[:media]) : TrackingPixel.all
[:page, :selective, :disabled].each do |attr|
  pixels = pixels.send(attr, params[attr]) if params[attr]
end
```